# Preselect option in form and propertyEditor

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-mvc-initbinders

I'm working with Spring in a web application, using forms and right now it's working fine, but i'd like to change one thing and that's when I get an error.
I have a small form with two text fields and one select option field and it's this select field that causes the errors. The select option is populated from the database.

My code:
edit.jsp

```
<tr>
 <th><label for="parent"></label></th>
 <td><sf:select path="parent">
  <sf:option value="0" label="Parent" />
  <sf:options items="${parentsList}" itemLabel="name" itemValue="ID"  />
  </sf:select></td>
</tr>
```

controller.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET, params = {"id"})
public String edit(Model model, @RequestParam("id") int id) {
    try {
        if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
            logger.info("Edit category with id {}", id);
        }

        model.addAttribute("heading", "Edit Category");
        model.addAttribute("parentsList", listOfParents());
        model.addAttribute(categoryService.getCategory(id));

        if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
            logger.info("Finished");
        }
    } catch (DataAccessException ex) {
        logger.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
    return "category/edit";
}

private List<Category> listOfParents() {
    List<Category> listOfParents = new ArrayList<Category>();
    try {

        listOfParents.addAll(categoryService.listCategoryParents());

    } catch (DataAccessException ex) {
        logger.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
    return listOfParents;
}

@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Category.class, "parent", new CategoryEditor(CategoryService));
}
```

My editor.java

```
public class CategoryEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {
private CategoryService categoryService;
public CategoryEditor(CategoryService categoryService) {
    this.categoryService = categoryService;
}

@Override
public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    if (text.equals("0")) {
        this.setValue(null);
    } else {
        category c = categoryService.getCategory(Integer.parseInt(text));
        this.setValue(sc);
    }
}
}
```

When I edit an already existing post I would like to have the parent preselected in the form and this is something I just can't get to work.

Is there anyone who can help me?
Thank you so much for your time and I hope I make any sence.
Thank you.

*EDIT***
I have now changed my editor to a formatter instead with no luck:

```
@Component
public class CategoryFormatter implements Formatter<Category> {

    @Override
    public String print(Category parent, Locale locale) {
        System.out.println("Formatter Print with ID="+parent.getID());
        return Integer.toString(parent.getID());
    }

    @Override
    public Category parse(String id, Locale locale) throws ParseException {
        Category parent = new Category();
        parent.setID(Integer.parseInt(id));
        System.out.println("Formatter Parse with ID="+parent.getID());
        return parent;
    }
}
```

But I still doesn't get the existing value in my drop down when I edit the object.
My print outs on edit object prints:

```
Formatter Print with ID=1
Formatter Parse with ID=0
Formatter Print with ID=1
Formatter Print with ID=8
```

What am I doing wrong?!?
(I would like to add a validator to this later on that's the reason for changing from editor to formatter)